# VSCode terminal settings

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

There is a directory structure something like given below-

```
Demo/
└── Project
    └── sample.py
```

I opened Project/ directory in the VS Code but the path shown in the terminal is from its root directory i.e., **shubhanshusingh@shubhanshusingh:~/Demo/Project$** that I don't want.

I want it to be like this **shubhanshusingh@shubhanshusingh:~/Project$**, that is, show only the name of the last directory. Is there any configuration that I can set for the VS Code terminal? Please let me know.

> I am using WSL:Ubuntu

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

Comment: But `~/Project` and `~/Demo/Project` _are different folders_. This is precisely why it shows you the path relative to your home folder `~/`. This path also makes it copy/pasteable to _other contexts_ in a way that is actually usable.

Comment: That said: https://superuser.com/questions/60555/show-only-current-directory-name-not-full-path-on-bash-prompt

Comment: Thanks, the given link has the solution for it.